# How can you regain your feet when you lose an edge snowboarding on steep terrain?

Tags: snowboarding

Last year I was snowboarding in Tignes (France). I was coming down a steep red run into La Daille (Orange on the map below) when I lost my edge (heel side). I'm not a great snowboarder...

[image]

So I ended up falling forwards (not seriously) with my feet facing down the slope. I landed on my backside and started sliding down the steep icy slope. I was in a sitting position and wanted to simply get back onto my board.

Nothing I did seems to either

- a) stop my slide or
- b) allow me to get enough traction on my edge to get back up onto my
  board.

I ended up sliding down the whole slope on my bum, complete with plumes of snow shooting into the air from my board. It was quite spectacular (to the point where people on the overhead chair lift whooped and cheered me much to my embarrassment). I do have a video off my go-pro somewhere, I'll have to see if I can dig it out...

While sliding, I tried to lever myself back on top of the board but I couldn't gain enough traction to actually lift myself off the snow and I couldn't get my edge to dig into the snow enough to slow/stop me.

What should I have done here? I know the real solution was to not lose my edge in the first place, but presuming I have, how do I arrest my slide and/or regain my edge and stand back onto the board?

Comment: I had to google what a red route is. Europeans must be so confused when they come to north america and all the rating colours are a full grade harder than what they're used to.

Comment: No, blues and greens are the same, and blacks are easier in North America.

Comment: Not sure if ithis is an answer, but i did use this in your situation: keep sliding, but turn around (looking uphill, sliding backwards) and do a backwrds roll onto your feet. I was younger, and am not sure how much of a possibility this is for other people (or me today, it has been 10 years...), but give it a try. Otherwise just get up while sliding, keep on sliding until in shape to build up edge-pressure to slow an stop.

Comment: that sounds very athletic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't going to get an edge while you're scraping down the slope. What you need to do is get your board pointed down the slope so you can turn and cut a new edge. You will gain some speed attempting this, but essentially what you need to do is get up and get your board under control before you can turn and get your edge back.

If you're on your butt, try to get your board under you and pointed down hill, once your weight is over your board, stand up and lean into your new edge.